# Laravel 4.2 -- New database session "exists", not saving + jasny/sso

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4, single-sign-on

Long story short: I have hacked jasny/sso to work with Laravel. It works extremely well except when the primary/root session has expired.

I have the primary/root authentication set to "remember", so it can reauthenticate from the cookie when the session has expired.

When the 'attach' action happens on the SSO server and the primary/root session has already expired, I am running Auth::check() to bring the session back to life so that it can be attached properly.

All of my debugging indicates that everything is working exactly as I need it to except for this one little detail:

**The new session generated by the 'attach' action is never written to the database because the DatabaseSessionHandler thinks it already exists. It is running an UPDATE instead of an INSERT.**

As a result, my SSO client session attaches to a non-existent SSO server session.

For the life of me, I can not figure out why it thinks this new session already exists nor how to get it to correctly insert into the database.

Can anyone tell me why a new Laravel 4.2 session would be detected as "exists" and run UPDATE instead of INSERT on save()?

EXTRA DEBUGGING ATTEMPTS --

Attempt #1: I have tracked this to a false attachment to an expired session that hasn't been garbage collected yet. What I don't understand is how this session is being loaded while a different session ID is being presented. If this were the result of the migrate() or regenerate() methods, "exists" would be set to false, and it would save correctly. Somehow, it seems that the session ID is being updated without resetting "exists".

Attempt #2: The answer was staring me in the face the whole time. I *kind of* understand the downvote now. (see my answer below)

Comment: Downvote without explanation? Classy move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was dramatically over-thinking this as I tried to uncover the mechanism behind the behavior instead of testing what looked like an easy solution:

If I call Session::setExists(false) prior to Session::save(), it will insert the new session correctly.

EDIT: If wrapped in an if-statement for Auth::viaRemember(), I can check if the auth happened via session or cookie/remember. If true, *then* I want to set "exists" to false.

Comment: This causes a fault when the Session actually still *does* exist.

Comment: Edited to address above comment.